# Infinite Loop Java for an unfathomable reason

Tags: java, loops, iterator

The code is supposed to partition the list into sets. If the ArrayList contains the same strings twice in a row, it will add their indexes to one HashSet otherwise the indexes will be in different HashSets. The point is to put the indexes of all the same strings from the ArrayList in the same HashSet and the indexes of the different strings in different HashSets. For example, the program SHOULD print [[0, 1][2, 3]] but it's stuck in an infinite loop. I put a print statement to verify whether the first two indexes are being added to the HashSet, which they are. The program prints [[0, 1]] instead of the expected result. For some reason, list.get(index1).equals(list.get(index2)) always evaluates to true even though I update the indexes in the loop and the result should be false at the second iteration.

```
package quiz;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Question {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Question q = new Question();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("a");
    list2.add("a");
    list2.add("c");
    list2.add("c");
    System.out.println(q.answer(list2));



}

public HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> answer(ArrayList<String> list){

    HashSet<HashSet<Integer>> hashSet = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();

        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 1;

        while (it.hasNext()){



            while (list.get(index1).equals(list.get(index2))){



                set.add(index1);
                set.add(index2);
                if (index1<list.size()-2){
                    index1=index1+1;
                    index2=index2+1;

                }

            }
            hashSet.add(set);
            System.out.println(hashSet);    
        }
        /*else{
            set.add(i);
        }*/



    return hashSet;
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: where do you call `it.next()`?

Comment: To expand upon what Boris the Spider is saying, simply getting an element from a list will not advance said list's iterator.

Comment: I love you guys so much right now :D

Comment: If you just want to count the number of duplicates why dont you just use a HashMap instead. HashMap of <Integer, Integer>. The first one is the integer and the second on its count

Answer (score 1):

You get an infinite loop because you are using the iterator hasNext() but not using the it.next() afterwards which move the index forward.

In addition, you do not really need the iterator because you are not using the values. You should do something like that:

```
while(shouldStop)
......
if (index1<list.size()-2){
   index1=index1+1;
   index2=index2+1;
} else {
   shouldStop=true
}
........
```